# Array pointer changes values when passed as parameter to other function

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, parameters

My problem is that when I am passing a pointer array "q" collected by function "sense" to other function "move" , the values in "q" gets randomly changes. Any response will be heartily appreciated. 
Here is my code:

```
Main()
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    int i,j,k;
    float *p=(float *)malloc(sizeof(float));
    float *q=(float *)malloc(sizeof(float));
    j=0;
    k=0;

    for(i=0;i<NCELLS;i++)
                 p[i]=1.0/NCELLS;

        q=sense(p,j); //Gives write values in q
    j++;

    q=move(q,motion[k]); // when passed to "move" values of q randomly changes
    k++;

    printf("\n");
    for(i=0;i<NCELLS;i++)
                printf("%f\t", q[i]);

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
functions:
float* move(float *p,int U)
{
    int i;
    float temp;
    float *next=(float *)malloc(sizeof(float));
    printf("\n");
    for(i=0;i<NCELLS;i++)
            printf("%f\t", p[i]); //Here I am checking for change in values
    for(i=0;i<NCELLS;i++)
    {
        temp=pGoal*p[mod(i-U,NCELLS)];  
        temp=temp+pOvershoot*p[mod(i-U+1,NCELLS)]; 
        temp=temp+pUndershoot*p[mod(i-U-1,NCELLS)]; 
        next[i]=temp;
    }  

    return(next);
}

float* sense(float *p,int j)
{
    int i;
        float *q, sum;
    q=(float *)malloc(sizeof(float));
        sum=0;
        for(i=0;i<NCELLS;i++)
        {
                if(strcmp(World[i],Sense[j])==0)
                        q[i]=pHit*p[i];
                else
                        q[i]=pMiss*p[i];

                        sum+=q[i];     
         }
     for(i=0;i<NCELLS;i++)
                q[i]=q[i]/sum;

    return(q);
}
```

Comment: please work on your indentation. Your code is pretty unreadable at this point.

Comment: I don't have the time to take a serious look at it, but printing as a debugging tool will only take you so far. Use a debugger to step thorough the code and examine the values deeply.

Comment: You have a memory leak here: `q=move(q,motion[k]);` and here: `q=sense(p,j);`. Memory allocated here: `float *q=(float *)malloc(sizeof(float));` will be lost.

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(float))` be allocated only one element.

Comment: @Charles NCELLS is 1.

Comment: @soon thanks for reply but how to prevent this memory leakage??

Comment: @user2444953, a) Do not overwrite address in the pointer, b) Do not allocate memory.

Comment: @CharlesBailey ohh sorry NCELLS is 5

Answer (score 0):

```
float *q=(float *)malloc(sizeof(float));
```

How many `float`s are you allocating? One.

```
for(i=0;i<NCELLS;i++)
            printf("%f\t", q[i]);
```

How many `float`s are you attempting to access? Five. Do you see a problem here? If you want five floats, allocate five floats:

```
float *q = malloc(5 * sizeof *q);
```

---

In your `move` function, you allocate and return a new array only to discard the old without destroying the old (using `free`) after returning. This causes a memory leak. Why do you even need `malloc`? Don't call `malloc` in these functions; Leave that decision for the caller (`main`) to make. In this case, the caller doesn't need dynamic allocation, so it benefits significantly from the choice. Use the right tool for the job...

I suggest adopting a style consistent to `memcpy` for these functions. Any external variables should be provided as arguments or inside structs that are provided as arguments.

```
void find_move(float *, float const *, size_t, size_t, float, float, float);
void find_sense(float *, float const *, size_t, char const * const *, char const *, float, float);

int main(void)
{
    float p[NCELLS], q[NCELLS];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < NCELLS; i++)
    {
        p[i] = 1.0 / NCELLS;
    }

    find_sense(q, p, NCELLS, world, sense[1], hit, miss);
    find_move(p, q, NCELLS, 0, goal, overshoot, undershoot);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < NCELLS; i++)
    {
        printf("%f\t", p[i]);
    }

    putchar('\n');
}

void find_move(float *destination, float const *source, size_t length, size_t offset, float goal, float overshoot, float undershoot)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        float temp = goal * source[mod(i - offset, length)]
                   + overshoot * source[mod(i - offset + 1, length)]
                   + undershoot * source[mod(i - offset - 1, length)];
        printf("%f\t", source[i]);
        destination[i] = temp;
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

void find_sense(float *destination, float const *source, size_t length, char const * const *world, char const *sense, float hit, float miss)
{
    float sum = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < NCELLS; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(world[i], sense) == 0)
        {
            destination[i] = hit * source[i];
        }
        else
        {
            destination[i] = miss * source[i];
        }

        sum += destination[i];     
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        destination[i] /= sum;
    }
}
```

P.S. Note the consistent whitespace and descriptive identifiers used here. I even put braces where people expect them, however unnecessary that may seem. I expect that if my code were hideous, you wouldn't want to decipher it. You'd probably ignore the answer and wait for a new one, much like most people will ignore your question and wait for a new one... Please keep this in mind when you present code to us.

Comment: Thanks a lot dear n yeah surely I will henceforth follow your advice. Again thanks a lot:)